# Linux OpenSSH ignore certificate creation time on host

Tags: linux, ssh, cryptography, embedded

I have an embedded Linux system which goes a while without power, and isn't always connected to the internet, so the time is never correct until a user actually interacts with the device, and even then I cannot guarantee retrieving the time if there is an issue. I have a SSH certificate used to sign SSH keys so I can login remotely/locally and allow others to do the same, however, since the time defaults to when the image was compiled, only keys that were signed before the image is compiled are accepted until the time is updated unless time is set.

Is there a way to configure the ssh daemon to ignore the creation time of a signed key, or modify the signing process using `ssh-keygen` to set a early creation date? I understand there are security implications with your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM I guess, I read the sshd_config docs but not the `ssh-keygen` manpage, for the next guy check out the -V option.

> -V validity_interval - Specify a validity interval when signing a certificate.  A validity interval may consist of a single time, indicating that the certificate is valid beginning now and expiring at that time, or may consist of two times separated by a colon to indicate an explicit time interval.

Tested, working.